# Django URLs linking

Tags: django, url, parameters

I have 2 buttons and when I click on one of them I want to be redirected to a new html page, using the id as a parameter.

**My URLs**

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls, name ='home'),
    path('dpo/imprimir/aprovado/<int:id>/',Aprovado, name ='aprovado'),
    path('dpo/imprimir/reprovado/<int:id>/',Reprovado, name ='reprovado'),
    ]
```

**My Template**

```html
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
<li>
    <a href="/dpo/imprimir/aprovado/{{instance.id}}">{% trans "Aprovado" %}</a>
</li>
<li>

    <a href="/dpo/imprimir/reprovado/{{instance.id}}">{% trans "Não aprovado" %}
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

**My views**

```html
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import Projeto


def Aprovado(request, id):
        obj = Projeto.objects.get(id=id)
        context = {
                "object": obj
        }
        return render(request, "dpo/imprimir/aprovado.html", context)

def Reprovado(request, id):
        obj = Projeto.objects.get(id=id)
        context = {
                "object": obj
        }
        return render(request, "dpo/imprimir/reprovado.html", context)
```

I think I'm doing this the wrong way.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: an error saying "page not found"

Comment: there's a closing `/` in your path, but you don't have it in your template. It's easier if you use the `{% url %}` template tag so you can use the path's name instead of duplicating urls and making small mistakes like this.

Comment: same error appears

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<a href="{% url 'aprovado' object.id %}">{% trans "Aprovado" %}</a>
<a href="{% url 'reprovado' object.id %}">{% trans "Não aprovado" %}
```

Comment: it is giving me this error "Reverse for 'aprovado' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dpo/imprimir/aprovado/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']"

Comment: try my updated answer

Comment: still the same error

Comment: ok just print `{{ object }}` in html template and give the output

Comment: when i print {{ object }} in html template, appears in white

Comment: make sure `obj = Projeto.objects.get(id=id)` return an object

Comment: he is returning something, because I made a print inside the view it really does print something  (number: 2165)

Comment: In template what is the value of `object.id` or `instance.id`

Comment: I'm not realizing what you're asking. When i open the object with id= 1 , i need this `<a href="/dpo/imprimir/aprovado/myobject_id">{% trans "Aprovado" %}</a>`, 
if I manually put the id, such as "1", it works right

Comment: but when i print the variable {{ object }} on the template , show the id on console

Answer (score 0):

Since the object instance name is given as `"object"` in the context, you need to refer it in the template, like

```
<a href="/dpo/imprimir/aprovado/{{object.id}}">{% trans "Aprovado" %}</a>
```

Comment: an error saying "page not found"